# CSS - Floating two elements side by side

Tags: css, css-float

I have two divs side by side. I want div that is on left hand side to take up as much room as it needs without pushing the other div (on right) to next line.

Here is what I have right now: http://jsfiddle.net/RALza/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="divA"> left text </div>
    <div id="divB">  right text </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#divA
{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:100%;
}

#divB
{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="divB">  right text </div>
    <div id="divA"> left text </div>
</div>

#divA
{
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

#divB
{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

will work.

But you should specify width of floating elements.

Comment: The content of div on left hand side varies. So I can't specify the width.

Comment: @dev.e.loper: You don't need to specify a `width`.

Comment: I mean for #divB in my code (but it seems it isn't necessary: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width)

Comment: @Mat Thanks. The following works. There is a problem though, if divB has lot of text the divs switch places and one goes under another. http://jsfiddle.net/RALza/17/

Comment: Just add a width (with width or max-width) to #divB

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS flexible boxes:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="divA">left text</div>
    <div id="divB">right text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RALza/6/

It works by changing the order of the two divs and making the first div a normal block element without a float.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="divB">  right text </div>
    <div id="divA"> left text </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#divA
{
  border:1px solid blue;
}

#divB
{
  float:right;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The following works however there is a problem if divA has lots of text. One div goes into another.  http://jsfiddle.net/RALza/16/