# Aligning two elements side by side and forcing them to stay on level

Tags: html, css

[CSS - Floating two elements side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168442/css-floating-two-elements-side-by-side)

This conversation is similar to what I am trying to achieve. I have a % based layout and have an issue either the menu will get mixed in with the content or the content will fall below the menu when the page is shrunk or viewed on a mobile phone. I've spent several hours on this and cant figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

Problem child: https://www.tendercare-inc.com/new/

Update:
My biggest thing was getting something that worked well with Word Press as it uses very awkward controls and element names. I tried starting with _Underscores but it doesn't seem to have helped as much as I thought it would.

Comment: need to post codes and where you have the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are specifying percentage based layouts for some elements like `menu-sidebar` and `main-content` but you're not consistent. The menu has a `min-width` of 200px. What do you want to happen when 200px is greater than 15%? Inside the menu you also have elements specified with exact pixel widths — the various cssmenu maker elements.

The site is very simple — basically a header, footer, side menu, and body. Yet you have two style sheets - one with over 800 lines — and a structure with `site-content` containing `content-area` containing `site-main` containing `content-container`. It's no wonder it's causing you grief. My advice would be to start over with a simple css framework (like bootstrap mentioned by @jaun above. Keep the structure of the html as simple as possible and avoid copy-paste design with things like menus. Also rather than trying things a seeing what's wrong, describe the behavior you want at various screen sizes and make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap (getbootstrap.com) you can use col-md-6 clases to do that. Also mobile phone and tablet ajustment is supported